# Flutter with firebase_admob

Tags: firebase, flutter, flutter-dependencies

In my project as and when i added the plugin firebase_admob: ^0.7.0 in the pubspec.yaml file the app stopped working. I mean to say as and when the app starts it is getting closed in a blink and shows alert box saying "App keeps stopping".

In console it prints the below logs...

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Initializing gradle...
Resolving dependencies...
Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
Built build\app\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk.
Installing build\app\outputs\apk\app.apk...
```

The app also got installed but never opens. But when I click on it to open it it says ABC app keep stopping... App info or close app

Dependencies in my **pubspec.yaml

```
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  share: ^0.5.3
  firebase_admob: ^0.7.0** // app stops working when added
```

I have also added my app_id to the **android_manifest.xml**

```
<meta-data
  android:name="io.flutter.app.android.SplashScreenUntilFirstFrame"
        android:value="true" />

  <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
        android:value="ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXX~XXXXXXXXXX"/>
```

I also addedbelow dependency to my app-level gradle..

```
dependencies {
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
        **implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.1'**
    }
```

Anyone faced this issue>

Thank you

Comment: Can you post the code you are using for showing ads?

Comment: @CopsOnRoad Thanks for your reply... Actually I have not put any code yet for the ads. But as and when I add firebase_admob dependency the app stops working..

Comment: lower the dependency  firebase_admob (0.6.1+1) and  add your AdMob app ID to the AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: @ShyjuMadathil I tried to lower the dependency but still the same issue. I have updated the question with more details. Thank you for your time and help

Comment: @Sam I have faced this issue and could fix the same by lowering the version.
check this issue https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/23215

Comment: Thank @ShyjuMadathil it solved my issue..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Able to get the app to open by changing: `firebase_admob: ^0.5.5

and

```
dependencies {
        api 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:15.0.1'
    }
```

And adding to the AndroidManifest.xml with my AdMob keys:

```
</activity>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APP_ID_HERE"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"/>
    </application>
```

[GitHub Issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/23215)

Comment: I am able to display Test ads without the below dependency

dependencies {
        api 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:15.0.1'
    }

Comment: In my case, I had `onAdFailedToLoad: 3`
`BannerAd` event is `MobileAdEvent.failedToLoad`. Though it didn't give me a sense, but now it shows the adds and BannerA is `MobileAdEvent.loaded`